# Sanity check on an open drain buffer (pull-up to 3.3V but 14V on gate?)

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, amplifier, open-drain

I want to make a simple open-drain buffer using the 2N7000 MOSFET. The input signal on the gate (Vgs) will be 14V and the voltage it is switching is 3.3V (Vds). Usually MOSFETs are used to switch higher voltages not lower ones so I just need a sanity check on whether this is possible. The max Vgs on the 2N7000 is 20V-40V so I'm not too worried about that and if it breaks I'm just working on a proof of concept anyway. Update: switching frequency is 2 times a second so no worries there.

[image]

Comment: gate-to-drain capacitance may give you grief if rise/fall times of the gate signal is fast.

Comment: Should be fine. In general, if a MOSFET gate is rated 20 V and 30 V absolute maximum, you will wear out the gate above 20 V and have short life expectancy. For a proof of concept on the bench, then no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rds(on) = 5 Ω  and Vgs max is 20V so this works fine as an inverting level level shifter.